# codeplex phpexcel select only cells with data

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm reading a spreadsheet and and dropping it into an array (I will shortly be inserting this into a database but for now im just doing a vardump for testing) using this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
?><pre><?php var_dump($sheetData);
```

Now this works great as I expected but the sheet has a large number of blank rows which are also returned in the array, is there a way of getting only the rows that contain data?

Comment: Actually, [there is a solution in similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14981808/531758)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, you'd need to loop each row returned by toArray(), checking each cell within that row to see if it is empty or not