# Ignore empty cells PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using the library [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to read data in an Excel file. The problem I'm having, is that when I use something like:

```
$obj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
$data = $obj->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

To load my file and convert its content into an array, I get all the columns and rows of my Excel file in my array even those without any data in them. Is there a method or something in the library PHPExcel to tell it to ignore cells in my Excel sheet that do not contain any data? (Instead of having a bunch of empty associative arrays in my `$data`)

Comment: do you want your array to eliminate its empty values (the elements in the array that are empty?)

Answer (score 15):

If your problem is in getting empty columns that go after real data, and you would like to avoid these, you could do something like this:

```
$maxCell = $sheet->getHighestRowAndColumn();
$data = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $maxCell['column'] . $maxCell['row']);
```

This will return array representing only the area containing real data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "area containing real data" but my max row is 1000 even though my sheet only has ~20 rows with data in them. In other words, this doesn't "filter" out blank rows for me using `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet version 1.18.0`.

Comment: This answer was true 8 years ago. I'm not sure if getHighestRowAndColumn method changed its behavior, but in my case when I used it it returned only rows with data. Are you sure that your rows really empty, sometimes they might contain something even if it is not visible.

Comment: Yeah, they're NULL. It's all good though. I just had to loop and filter. I short circuited the loop when finding the first completely empty row to avoid looping through all 1000. Fast enough. Thanks for the answer BTW.

Answer (score 11):

I have this solution for my case

```
$maxCell = $objWorksheet->getHighestRowAndColumn();
$data = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $maxCell['column'] . $maxCell['row']);
```

return all rows with all empty string as:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
        )
```

To remove these empty rows

```
$data = array_map('array_filter', $data);
```

will return

[1] => Array
        (
        )

And this is the finale solution:

```
        $maxCell = $objWorksheet->getHighestRowAndColumn();
        $data = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $maxCell['column'] . $maxCell['row']);
        $data = array_map('array_filter', $data);
        $data = array_filter($data);
```

will return an array with only filled rows .. hope that help

Comment: Isn't needed to use `array_map`, `array_filter($data)` can be used directly in that case 

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't. The toArray() method returns the first argument (NULL) to represent an empty cell. You can then apply standard PHP array functions such as array_filter() to eliminate empty cells.

```
foreach($data as $key => &$row) {
    $row = array_filter($row,
                        function($cell) {
                            return !is_null($cell);
                        }
           );
    if (count($row) == 0) {
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
unset ($row);
```

This will eliminate every cell that is a NULL (empty) value, and every row that comprises nothing but empty cells. It will preserve the array keys, so your array keys will still give you a cell reference.

Note that an cell containing an empty string is not a null cell, so these will be retained, although the array_filter() callback could be modified to remove them as well.

Comment: I'm trying to import an excel file with 14k+ rows using rangeToArray(), but it takes quite some time to importe and often end with 504 Gateway Timeout. Do you have any suggestions? Is the exemple you gave above a better way than using rangeToArray()?

Comment: @JCharette - If you're working with large workbooks, it's better not to create large arrays in memory as well, but to process row by row (rangeToArray) can extract a row from the worksheet each time, but don't try to get the entire worksheet to an array

Comment: If you're working with large workbooks, it's also a lot better to process as a background task rather than as part of a browser request

Comment: Thanks for you recommandations. I'm trying to understand how processing row by row would be faster?

Comment: When working with large workbooks, it's better for memory usage because you don't have an enormous worksheet array in memory as well as the PHPExcel object; and it's often better for performance because PHP doesn't need to spend time allocating that large volume of memory, especially as it would otherwise request that memory in a lot of small (cell sized) blocks.

Comment: @MarkBaker how to eliminate complete row if all columns are empty