# PHPExcel read empty cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library to get data from cells. I implemented `PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter` iterface and set it in my reader object to read data from custom `range(B1:J50 e.g)`. It works fine but reader doesn't get empty cells, but i need to get them. I call `IterateOnlyExistingCells(false)`, but reader ignoring my filter and get all cells.

```
class CellsFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
        private $startCellName;
        private $startCellValue;
        private $endCellName;
        private $endCellValue;
        private $additionalCells;


        public function __construct($strRange)  {
            $this->initializeRange($strRange);          
        }

        public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {

            if ($row >= $this->startCellValue && $row <= $this->endCellValue) {
                if (in_array($column, range($this->startCellName, $this->endCellName))) {                   
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285511/ignore-empty-cells-phpexcel helps?

Comment: Read Filters have nothing to do with the row and cell iterators: A read filter tells the PHPExcel Reader only to read data for a defined set of cells; iterators loop through the rows and columns: is your problem that the iterator is still looping through column A? If so, please show the iterator code rather than the readfilter code