# Failed to run query: 1048 Column 'element_oppningar' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to import xls to mysql.
I recently switched connection to PDO.
But then an error accord.
Fields in my xls that is NULL are no longer accepted.
Why? How can i change my code to accept NULL value?

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
echo '<a href=".php">Fortsätt...</a><br  />';
echo $path=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

//Load file into PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

//Loop threw file to get data
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = 'J'; //$worksheet->getHighestColumn(''); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

//Echo file info
echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';

//Loop threw colum, rows and cells
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
        //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
        echo '<td>' . $val . '<br></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
$val=array();
for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
$cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
$val[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
// Prepare Query 
    $query = "INSERT INTO table(
                objekt_nr,
                objekt_rev,
                element_nr,
                element_hojd,
                element_typ,
                element_langd,
                element_oppningar,
                element_vikt,
                element_ritare,
                element_status) 
            VALUES ( 
            :objekt_nr, 
            :objekt_rev, 
            :element_nr,
            :element_hojd,
            :element_typ,
            :element_langd,
            :element_oppningar,
            :element_vikt,
            :element_ritare,
            :element_status
        )"; 

    // Security measures
    $query_params = array(  
        ':objekt_nr' => $val[0],
        ':objekt_rev' => $val[1],
        ':element_nr' => $val[2],
        ':element_hojd' => $val[3],
        ':element_typ' => $val[4],
        ':element_langd' => $val[5],
        ':element_oppningar' => $val[6],
        ':element_vikt' => $val[7],
        ':element_ritare' => $val[8],
        ':element_status' => $val[9]
    ); 
    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); }
```

Comment: your db has the field defined as `not null`. There is NOTHING you can do in your code to override that, other than by doing an `alter` on the table and removing the not null constraint.

Comment: @MarcB Ok. So, when i used mysql i was sending in an "" empty value. That was why i didn't get this message. The loop stops if there is a NULL so, how can i change the code to send in "" empty value like the mysql did? Now with PDO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accept a NULL value you have to edit the database table, not the code. Your message error is generated by MySQL, not the PHP.

Comment: Ok. So, when i used mysql i was sending in an "" empty value. That was why i didn't get this message. The loop stops if there is a NULL so, how can i change the code to send in "" empty value like the mysql did? Now with PDO?

Comment: Have you tried [these methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285511/ignore-empty-cells-phpexcel)?