# PHPExcel to html gives empty cells

Tags: php, html, phpexcel, xlsx

Im Using the PHPExcel library to convert a uploaded .xlsx file to a html page.

The code works but the html page also has alot of empty cells in it. what can i do so PHPExcel wil not create these?

**the convert**

```
$inputFileName = $upload_dir;
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save($basename.".html");
```

**the result**
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore empty cells PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285511/ignore-empty-cells-phpexcel)

Comment: What do you want to happen to these empty cells? What do you expect to be displayed in the HTML markup?

Comment: @MarkBaker preferably gone from the document, these files ar meant so be shown on a mobile devices. so i would like the document to be as small in collumn and row size as possible. so they would fit on the screen better.

Comment: You'll have to write yourself a custom HTML Writer that ignores empty cells when generating the markup then, this isn't something that PHPExcel does, or wants to do, because it's not reflecting the actual content of the spreadsheet.... if a spreadsheet contains an empty cell, then the HTML writer shows exactly that; offsetting columns because of an empty cell in a row would not be the writing the data from the spreadsheet as it exists in the spreadsheet

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the advice! so this also means if i startoff with a new spreatsheet file. and do not touch the structure anywhere else then needed. PHPExcel would not write it?

Comment: Not sure that I follow your logic here? Why wouldn't PHPExcel write a valid spreadsheet file?

Comment: @MarkBaker my bad, I meant not write the the empty cells. I have allready tried it and it works as i thought. Thanks for the support Mark!