# Ignore empty cells with phpexcel

Tags: php, html, sql, phpexcel

i'm really new with PHPExcel library,and i'm new with this kind of programming.
So my problem is i just wanna read a cells with a value in it, and ignore all the empty cell below my tables. can i do that?
My Excel file:

[image]

I know this question is simillar to this [Ignore empty cells PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285511/ignore-empty-cells-phpexcel) thread, but i can't find the answer there, so please can someone help me..

My code for converting excel:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a validation inside the 2nd loop to check if all the required columns are empty, and if they're, skip that iteration. Example:

```
// Skip the iteration if all the required columns are empty
if(ltrim($aop_part_num) == '' && ltrim($type) == '' && ltrim($brand) == '' && ltrim($jumlah) == '') continue;
```

However, if the Excel file *may* have some more stuff below that table you're parsing (even if it has blank space in between), then replace the "continue" for a "break" to quit the loop and prevent that extra stuff from showing up in the echo statements.