# Remove empty rows in PHPexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have the following code .

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestDataRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . 
       $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);

}
```

I need to ignore rows if all columns are empty.I have seen links [ignore empty columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285511/ignore-empty-cells-phpexcel) ,but am not sure about this will work for me. I dont need to eliminate columns if it is empty,but I need to eliminate entire row,if all the columns are empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate the row and check that all cells are empty.

Sample code

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestDataRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
    if(isEmptyRow(reset($rowData))) { continue; } // skip empty row
    // do something usefull
}

function isEmptyRow($row) {
    foreach($row as $cell){
        if (null !== $cell) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code i used,which code snippet get the only area of data inserted

Thanks,

```
$inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);//Get the area of data inserted
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);




$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestDataRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
```